# Find out the recently selected rows from a Oracle table and can I update a LAST_ACCESSED column whenever the table is accessed

Tags: database, oracle

I have a database table which have more than 1 million records uniquely identified by a GUID column. I want to find out which of these record or rows was selected or retrieved in the last 5 years. The select query can happen from multiple places. Sometimes the row will be returned as a single row. Sometimes it will be part of a set of rows. there is select query that does the fetching from a jdbc connection from a java code. Also a SQL procedure also fetches data from the table.

My intention is to clean up a database table.I want to delete all rows which was never used( retrieved via select query) in last 5 years.

Does oracle DB have any inbuild meta data which can give me this information.

My alternative solution was to add a column LAST_ACCESSED and update this column whenever I select a row from this table. But this operation is a costly operation for me based on time taken for the whole process. Atleast 1000 - 10000 records will be selected from the table for a single operation. Is there any efficient way to do this rather than updating table after reading it. Mine is a multi threaded application. so update such large data set may result in deadlocks or large waiting period for the next read query.

Any elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: How large is the table in segment size?  (That is, `select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024/1024 tb from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TABLE_NAME';`.)  I have a feeling the only 100% accurate solutions will be painful to write and maintain.  Unless the data is ginormous it's probably not worth doing this.

Comment: i can't execute the above. I don't have permission on the actual table. I have a replicate or a subset of the actual table. But the table have huge number of entries. an estimated number of entres per year is 89560923 rows.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Why are you spending time cleaning up this table?  If you don't know the size of the table in bytes I assume you don't care about saving disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use any inbuild solutions. i tried below solutions
1)DB audit feature for select statements.
2)adding a trigger to update a date column whenever a select query is executed on the table.

Both were discarded. Audit uses up a lot of space and have performance hit. Similary trigger also had performance hit.

Finally i resolved the issue by maintaining a separate table were entries older than 5 years that are still used or selected in a query are inserted. While deleting I cross check this table and avoid deleting entries present in this table.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Database 12c introduced a new feature called [Automatic Data Optimization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/automatic-data-optimization-wp-12c-1896120.pdf) that brings you [Heat Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-FB83C140-B7E7-4EF8-959A-A990ECE20369.htm#VLDBG14124) to track table access (modifications as well as read operations). Careful, the feature is [currently to be licensed under the Advanced Compression Option or In-Memory Option](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/DBLIC/Licensing-Information.htm#DBLIC-GUID-B6113390-9586-46D7-9008-DCC9EDA45AB4).

Heat Maps track whenever a database block has been modified or whenever a segment, i.e. a table or table partition, has been accessed. It does not track select operations per individual row, neither per individual block level because the overhead would be too heavy (data is generally often and concurrently read, having to keep a counter for each row would quickly become a very costly operation). However, if you have you data partitioned by date, e.g. create a new partition for every day, you can over time easily determine which days are still read and which ones can be archived or purged. Also Partitioning is an option that needs to be licensed.

Once you have reached that conclusion you can then either use [In-Database Archiving](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5A76B6CE-C96D-49EE-9A89-0A2CB993A933.htm#VLDBG14154) to mark rows as archived or just go ahead and purge the rows. If you happen to have the data partitioned you can do easy `DROP PARTITION` operations to purge one or many partitions rather than having to do conventional `DELETE` statements.

Comment: the trouble here,is that the data was create arround 5 years back and new data creation is very few. the rows created 5 years back are still accessed or used even today. So creating a partition is not a solution. I will check the Heap maps option. Thanks for the reply

Comment: There is no trouble here, you can partition a table even when there is already data inside it. The database is smart enough to move already existing data into the right partition and does it in a consistent online manner. Check out [Converting a Non-Partitioned Table to a Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/VLDBG/evolve-nopartition-table.htm#VLDBG-GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5) in the documentation.
So you can still today partition your data from 5 years ago the way it fits your Information Lifecycle Management strategy today.

Comment: I don't want to split the data based on created date but instead the cleanup should be based on date of access or select or last used. Your solution doesn't provide a way to find when a row was last 'select' ed.